# Oracle function to replace all names to their nick names?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table called nicknames

```
Names   nickname
vikram  vik
James   Jim
Robert  Bob
Charles Dick
Richard Dick
Rich    Dick
```

Want to create an Oracle function to replace names with their nicknames from the table in an input string

func_nicknames('vikram, James, Rajesh, Robert') should return the value 'vik, Jim, Rajesh, Bob'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_nicknames( in_val varchar2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
O_VAL VARCHAR2(100) := in_val;
BEGIN
SELECT REPLACE(O_VAL,t.name,t.nickname) INTO O_VAL FROM nicknames t;
RETURN(O_VAL);
END func_nicknames;
```

The above code is throwing an error.

In SQL Server, the below code works fine:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION getNicknames(@val NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @result = @val;
    SELECT @result = REPLACE(@result, name, nickname)
    FROM nicknames;
    RETURN @result;
END;
```

Similar code I want to create in Oracle.
Working code for oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getNicknames(in_val VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR IS
ret VARCHAR(2000);
v VARCHAR(2000);
CURSOR cur IS SELECT SRC_VAL_STR, TGT_VAL_STR FROM nicknames;
BEGIN
    ret := in_val;
    FOR x IN cur
    LOOP
    SELECT REPLACE(ret, x.name, x.nickname) INTO v FROM DUAL;
    ret := v;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN ret;
END;
```

Comment: What if the name you supply does not have a nickname?

Comment: Are we to guess the error?

Comment: I guess it is "too many rows" :D

Comment: Yes, it is throwing an error  "too many rows"

Answer (score 3):

First you have to convert the parameter to a table, the rest is very straightforward:

```
create or replace function getNicknames (names varchar2) return varchar2 is
    ret varchar2 (32000);
begin
    with names (name) as (
        select trim (column_value)
        from xmlTable (('"'||replace (names, ',', '","')||'"')) x
    )
    select 
        listagg (coalesce (nickname, na.name), ', ') within group (order by null) into ret 
    from names na
    left join nicknames ni on ni.name=na.name;
    return ret;
end;
/
```

Execution and outcome:

```
exec dbms_output.put_line ('result='||getNicknames ('vikram, James, Rajesh, Robert'));    

result=vik, Jim, Rajesh, Bob
```

[On db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=140f6b38925d9c13c3925116209b6390).

Comment: When trying the below code:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION withNicknames(in_val varchar2) RETURN varchar2 IS
ret VARCHAR2(2000);
v varchar2(2000);
DECLARE 
CURSOR cur IS SELECT name, nickname FROM nicknames;
BEGIN
 ret := in_val;
 FOR x IN cur 
 LOOP
 SELECT REPLACE(ret, x.name, x.nickname) INTO v FROM DUAL;
 ret := v;
 END LOOP;
 RETURN ret;
END;
SELECT IRIS_TX('names/tx_nicknames', 'Hello Vikram') FROM DUAL;`
It is showing function is in an invalid state.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL returns more than one row. It is an error.
Try this:

```
create or replace function f_nicks (pNames in varchar2) 
 return varchar2
 is
     tab dbms_utility.uncl_array;  
     nCntElements number := 0;  
     vEl varchar2(32000);  
     o_nicks varchar2(1000);
 BEGIN  
    dbms_utility.comma_to_table(pNames, nCntElements, tab);  
   
     select  listagg (nvl( n.nickname, t.listname), ',') nicks into o_nicks
        from (select trim(column_value) listname, rownum lp 
             from table(tab) ) t , nicknames n   where n.name (+) =  t.listname  ;
 

  return o_nicks;
 END;
```

--- Test function

```
select f_nicks ('James, vikram, James,James, Rajesh, Robert') from dual;
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b321ba3f05f5b8916901774f1012118b)